# unity gameObject position always retrun to 0 and to center

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hello everyone i started to learn unity game engine and c# and i follow a video course step by step but when i press the play button its immediatly center the game object and when i try to move its moving but always returning to center(position 0,0,0)

```
public class PlayerMovment : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 pos = transform.position;

        pos.x = h * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        pos.y = v * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use the previous position at all. Just think about your math...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *add* your movement to the position, not overwriting it. Try this:

```
Vector2 pos = transform.position;

pos.x += h * speed * Time.deltaTime;
pos.y += v * speed * Time.deltaTime;

transform.position = pos;
```

Comment: could (should) use a vector instead `var input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));` .... and `transform.position += input * speed * Time.deltaTime;` I say should because this way you can additionally insert `input = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(input, 1);` making sure you are not faster overall when moving diagonal ;)